how to find the executable file in sigularity sif
I have pulled a docker file and have built a singularity (.sif) image.
When I run the following command:
singularity exec software.sif command

I get the error below:
FATAL:   "command": executable file not found in $PATH

How can I find my executable command in the .sif?
Thank you!
